# How to arrange every character ascending in a vector with words?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector, c++14

I want to arrange every word like this:

Input

```
5
viguo
lkjhg
tyujb
asqwe
cvbfd
```

OUTPUT

```
aeqsw
bcdfv
bjtuy
ghjkl
giouv
```

I want some ideas from you.
Thanks!

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: `std::sort` both for word and for `vector`.

Comment: How would you do this "by hand"? First rearrange the characters of each word, then rearrange the resulting words, probably. So your first question should be "how do I get sorted-by-character words into the vector?"

Comment: I suspect that you're assuming this to be complicated and overthinking it. You only need to add one (1) line, and it is almost identical to one of your other lines. (`std::string` is also a sequence, with `begin()` and `end()`.)

Comment: ok, thanks. Now i want to analyse the code from below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the algorithm `std::sort` two times.

The first one for each element of the vector and the second one for the vector itself.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v =
    {
        "viguo", "lkjhg", "tyujb", "asqwe", "cvbfd"
    };

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( auto &s : v ) std::sort( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ) );

    std::sort( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
viguo lkjhg tyujb asqwe cvbfd 
aeqsw bcdfv bjtuy ghjkl giouv
```

Comment: thanks for example. I try to learn more programming every day.